# Rank () function over multiple columns in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, top-n

I need to rank a table with two columns transID & travel_date

here is my data

```
transID    travel_date
2341       2018-04-04 10:00:00
2341       2018-04-04 11:30:00
2891       2018-04-04 12:30:00
2891       2018-04-04 18:30:00
2341       2018-04-05 11:30:00
2891       2018-04-05 22:30:00
```

this is the query which i have tried

```
 select transID,travel_date,rn,
    dense_rank () over (partition by transID order by EarliestDate,transID) as rn2
    from
    (SELECT transID,travel_date,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY transID ORDER BY travel_date) AS rn, 
             max(travel_date) OVER (partition by travel_date) as EarliestDate
      FROM travel_log_info
     ) t
     order by transID;
```

Current Output from the above query

```
transID    travel_date            rn2
2341       2018-04-04 10:00:00    1
2341       2018-04-04 11:30:00    2
2341       2018-04-05 11:30:00    3
2891       2018-04-04 12:30:00    1
2891       2018-04-04 18:30:00    2
2891       2018-04-05 22:30:00    3
```

Expected Output

```
transID    travel_date            rn2
2341       2018-04-04 10:00:00    1
2341       2018-04-04 11:30:00    2
2341       2018-04-05 11:30:00    1
2891       2018-04-04 12:30:00    1
2891       2018-04-04 18:30:00    2
2891       2018-04-05 22:30:00    1
```

with this output, I can get the desired output by where condition rn2 = 1 to get the output based on travel date and transId.

I am not getting the desired output as shown above. Kindly provide suggestions to achieve the correct output.
Thanks for your time

Comment: Alas, it's highly unlikely that the anonymous downvoter will come back to explain themselves. There are two ways you could improve your question. (1) Show us the actual result you get instead of just saying you don't get the expected output. (2) Explain the business rules you have which produce the result instead of expecting us to reverse engineer them from your desired output.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am a novice starting to swim in StackOverflow. Will definitely improve with my posts soon.

Comment: Can you please add more row in required Output, otherwise it's look very easy and you can achieve this only select transID,travel_date FROM travel_log_info ORDER BY travel_date desc.

Comment: @GulamHusainAnsari Edited my question.thanks

Comment: What are you looking for? The "*Required output*" or "*Expected Output*"?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I am looking at the expected output. (Removed the required output from the question).thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem with what you have now is:

```
max(travel_date) OVER (partition by travel_date)
```

which includes the time part of each date in the partition - so you're really getting the max of every individual date/time, which is that date/time. You seem to want maximum date/time within each day, so you could partition by each *day* by using `trunc()` in the partition-by clause:

```
max(travel_date) OVER (partition by trunc(travel_date))
```

Just that change gives you:

```
   TRANSID TRAVEL_DATE                 RN        RN2
---------- ------------------- ---------- ----------
      2341 2018-04-04 10:00:00          1          1
      2341 2018-04-04 11:30:00          2          1
      2341 2018-04-05 11:30:00          3          2
      2891 2018-04-04 12:30:00          1          1
      2891 2018-04-04 18:30:00          2          1
      2891 2018-04-05 22:30:00          3          2
```

The partitioning in the outer query is also wrong though, you need to partition by that 'earliest' date (actually latest, but doesn't matter for this):

```
select transID,travel_date,rn,
    dense_rank () over (partition by transID,EarliestDate order by travel_date) as rn2
    from
    (SELECT transID,travel_date,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY transID ORDER BY travel_date) AS rn, 
             max(travel_date) OVER (partition by trunc(travel_date)) as EarliestDate
      FROM travel_log_info
     ) t
     order by transID;

   TRANSID TRAVEL_DATE                 RN        RN2
---------- ------------------- ---------- ----------
      2341 2018-04-04 10:00:00          1          1
      2341 2018-04-04 11:30:00          2          2
      2341 2018-04-05 11:30:00          3          1
      2891 2018-04-04 12:30:00          1          1
      2891 2018-04-04 18:30:00          2          2
      2891 2018-04-05 22:30:00          3          1
```

But you don't really need that max, or the outer query you currently have; if you include that truncated day in the `row_number()` partition (which you currently aren't really using) you get:

```
SELECT transID,travel_date,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY transID, trunc(travel_date) ORDER BY travel_date) AS rn
FROM travel_log_info;

   TRANSID TRAVEL_DATE                 RN
---------- ------------------- ----------
      2341 2018-04-04 10:00:00          1
      2341 2018-04-04 11:30:00          2
      2341 2018-04-05 11:30:00          1
      2891 2018-04-04 12:30:00          1
      2891 2018-04-04 18:30:00          2
      2891 2018-04-05 22:30:00          1
```

and you can then wrap that in an outer query to filter on `rn`:

```
SELECT transID,travel_date
FROM (
  SELECT transID,travel_date,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY transID, trunc(travel_date) ORDER BY travel_date) AS rn
  FROM travel_log_info
)
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY transID,travel_date;

   TRANSID TRAVEL_DATE        
---------- -------------------
      2341 2018-04-04 10:00:00
      2341 2018-04-05 11:30:00
      2891 2018-04-04 12:30:00
      2891 2018-04-05 22:30:00
```

You could also do this without a subquery; this gets the same result [using `first`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/FIRST.html):

```
SELECT transID,
  min(travel_date) keep (dense_rank first order by travel_date) as travel_date
FROM travel_log_info
GROUP BY transID, trunc(travel_date)
ORDER BY transID, travel_date;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the perfect answer. I tried this ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY transID, travel_date ORDER BY travel_date) and it returned row num as 1 for all rows. Can you help to explain how it differs with the answer?

Comment: That's what the very start of my answer talks about. The value you're partitioning by is a single point-in-time value for the ID, say, 2341/2018-04-05 11:30:00. The maximum of that single value is always going to be that value - so the max for every row is the value from that row.

Comment: sorry I missed out that part. Thanks for the detailed explanation.